# Yesod: Custom divs and forms

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

How to make Yesod generate complicated forms like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text1" class="control-label col-lg-4">
      Normal Input Field
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input type="text" id="text1" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-group -->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pass1" class="control-label col-lg-4">
      Password Field
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
      <input class="form-control" type="password" id="pass1" data-original-title="Please use your secure password" data-placement="top" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I know that Yesod can create a generic form but is it possible to do the following things:

- Wrap a `div` around a textbox
- Wrap the label and input textbox also in another div.

Does Yesod allow to do these stuff for generating highly customized forms ?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms) you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yesod provides the ability of defining custom fields which is very well explained in their [documentation.](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms)

Also, I define two custom fields for the above problem:

```
textBoxField :: Text -> Field Handler Text
textBoxField label = Field
               { fieldParse = \rawVals _ ->
                 case rawVals of
                   [a] -> return $ Right $ Just a
                   [] -> return $ Right Nothing
               , fieldView = \idAttr nameAttr otherAttrs eResult isReq ->
                 [whamlet|
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <label for=#{idAttr} class="control-label col-lg-4">#{label}
                       <div class="col-lg-8">
                           <input id=#{idAttr} name=#{nameAttr} *{otherAttrs}
                                  type="text" class="form-control">
                  |]
               , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
               }

cPasswordField :: Text -> Field Handler Text
cPasswordField label = Field
               { fieldParse = \rawVals _ ->
                 case rawVals of
                   [a] -> return $ Right $ Just a
                   [] -> return $ Right Nothing
               , fieldView = \idAttr nameAttr otherAttrs eResult isReq ->
                 [whamlet|
                  <div class="form-group">
                       <label for=#{idAttr} class="control-label col-lg-4">#{label}
                       <div class="col-lg-8">
                           <input id=#{idAttr} name=#{nameAttr} *{otherAttrs}
                             type="password" class="form-control"
                             data-original-title="Please use your secure password" data-placement="top">
                  |]
               , fieldEnctype = UrlEncoded
               }
```

These functions can be later utilized to build up the actual form. The entire working code is [here.](https://github.com/psibi/rwh/blob/master/yesod/forms/Example.hs)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into `runInputPost` and `ireq`? Else look at the [form chapter in the yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms).

But, to give you an example, you can create exactly the form you want, and then just use something like this in the POST request,

```
-- Handling the blog article form
postAdminNewArticleR :: Handler Html
postAdminNewArticleR = do
    title <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "form-title-field"
    htmlContent <- runInputPost $ ireq htmlField "form-htmlcontent-field"
    -- insert into the database or something
```

For the form handler itself, you'd probably do,

```
-- The form page for posting a new blog article
getAdminNewArticleR :: Handler Html
getAdminNewArticleR = do
    formroute <- return $ AdminNewArticleR
    defaultLayout $ do
        -- ...
```

and lastly, the hamlet for the form page would look like,

```
<form method=post action=@{formroute}>
    <input name="form-title-field">
    <textarea name="form-htmlcontent-field">
```

This gives you 100% control of the forms.